# Is there any downside to increasing the ReservedCodeCacheSize in Java 7?

Tags: java, jboss7.x

While optimising an application I had deployed to JBoss 7, I ended up increasing the ReservedCodeCacheSize after getting the error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been 
disabled. 
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size 
using XXReservedCodeCacheSize=
```

I understand that the default settings for ReservedCodeCacheSize should be applicable to most applications, but I did wonder, apart from increasing the memory you use, is there any downside to increasing this size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never saw this error again, even after removing the increased ReservedCodeCacheSize.

However, the following link tested an application with varying sizes of ReservedCodeCacheSize and saw improved performance when testing with Java 1.5. The answer therefore seems to be, 'Measure, Don't Guess' :-)

http://xmlandmore.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/performance-tuning-with-hotspot-vm.html